# Simulation of a light source in a scene?

Tags: gimp, lighting-effects

I have photos of LEGO scenes with several objects, walls, surfaces etc. in them. Currently, there are no lights in the scenes, except for the lapms that light the scene from outside. The goal is to add glowing objects like computer screens, lamps etc. that are inside of the scene.

Since I don't have real miniature lamps and lights, I would like to simulate the effect that added lights and lamps would have on objects. **For example, how is the face of a Lego minifigure affected by the glowing of a blue screen in front of it?**

I am not aiming at perfect results (no physically correct phong/reflection/caustics etc.), rather at methods that yield reasonable approximations of glowing and reflection effects. My tools are Gimp, Inkscape, Krita, ImageMagick, POV-Ray and Linux scripting knowledge.

At the moment, I am thinking of adding coloured, semi-transparent layers to selected areas of the images, but maybe there are graphic or painting "tricks" available, that give good results.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think the OP"s question is answered by *Filters>Light and Shadows>Lighting effects* and especially by the "Environment map" tab.

Comment: Thank you, @xenoid, for your comment. I admit, my question is not very clear, but you guessed correctly: Bump map or Environment map allow to brighten only parts of an image, namely the surfaces that point towards the light source. Color and other properties can also be selected. This seems to be an excellent solution! If you make this an answer I would accept it.

Comment: As soon as @Ryan unlocks it :)

Comment: there you go @xenoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at *Filters>Light and Shadows>Lighting effects* and especially at the *Environment map* tab (which is a picture whose tints are reflected in the object). You may also want to add a bump map to help create the right shadows.